# How to prevent base 64 format signature images being dropped in Outlook Web App when updating the email body with Office.js?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I’m working on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook to add content to a draft email in compose view.

Our add-in fetches the existing content of the draft with the Office.js method `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()` using a coercion type of HTML, adding our new content to the HTML that is returned, and then replacing the draft email’s body with our updated HTML using the method `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync()` with a coercion type of HTML again.

It looks like when we do this from inside the Outlook Web App, any base 64 format images in the signature are dropped when we set the email’s body using the `setAsync()` method. Looking at the email body html, I see that the  element still exists in the email, but it has no src attribute anymore.

Is there anything we can do to prevent these images from being lost?

I’ve noticed in the Office.js documentation there is a `prependAsync()` method to prepend content to the email body without changing the rest of it. Is there a way to reliably append content to the end of the email body too?  If so, we could use that as a workaround in our case.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting base 64 encoded images is currently not supported in the Outlook Add-in platform. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/filters/top?category_id=131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.